# How to toggle JQueryUI Draggable on/off in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I wrote a block of code (below) that toggles JQuery Draggable on/off on an element. 
In short , when you click a div called *button* it toggles the draggable effect on/off on *another* div called **dragBlock**

This took me awhile but I finally got it working. The question I have is I don't understand why the code below doesn't work with only one **Draggable** instance. Mainly the one that uses the **state** argument.

```
$(dragBlock ).draggable(state);
```

Instead it only works when I use this:

```
$(dragBlock ).draggable(state);
$(dragBlock ).draggable();           // This line is needed for the code to work. Why?
```

This isn't a big issue but I would like to know why this is and I figure someone here might be able to explain it. **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taoist/rGNNW/)** is here:

And the code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var state = "disable";
   var button = document.getElementById("button");
   var dragBlock = document.getElementById("dragBlock");
   var toggle = function() {

   if (state==="enable") {
       state = "disable";
   }
   else if(state==="disable") {
       state = "enable";
   }

   $(dragBlock ).draggable(state);
   $(dragBlock ).draggable();           // This line is needed for the code to work. Why?
   console.log(state);
};
  button.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should really have the `.draggable()` outside the event handler, and only the `.draggable(state)` inside.

Calling `.draggable()` is how you initially setup the draggable functionality on the element.

Calling `.draggable('enable')` or `.draggable('disable')` is a way to enable or disable an already-configured draggable element. It's a way to interact with a draggable element that you've already setup.

Note though, that by calling draggable() outside the event handler your default initial state will now be `enabled`. You need to either disable it immediately or change your initial value for the `state` variable.

You can initialize the draggable and leave it disabled with this (outside the event handler)

```
('#dragBlock').draggable({disabled: true});
```

And then you'll only need the `.draggable(state)` inside the event handler.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle but it introduced a problem. I want the initial state of draggable to be disable. I tried modifying your code and couldn't figure out how to get this result. Ironically I think this might have been the initial problem that lead to my current code.